# Integration in ADV calculus

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be such that $f(x)=x^2$ for each $x\in [a,b]$. Use the definition to show that $f$ is integrable and

$\int_a^b f = \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}\,.$

Comment: I dont know what definition to look for

Comment: Which definitions do you have ? Assuming this is Riemann integral you must show that the $\inf$ of upper Riemann sums is equal to the $\sup$ of lower Riemann sums, where both $\inf$ and $\sup$ are taken on all the partitions of $[a,b]$. Does this ring any bells ? We can help you only if you at least give us something to work with. Please edit you post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first show that $ \int_0^b x^2 dx = \frac{b^3}{3}$ for all $b > 0$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the partition $P_n = \{x_0, x_1,...x_n\}$ of $[0,b]$ with $x_k = k\frac{b}{n}.$

Using the fact that $x^2$ is increasing on $[0,b]$, the upper Riemann sum
$$U(f,P_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n M_i(x_i - x_{i-1})$$
where  $M_i = \sup\{f(x) : x \in [x_{i-1},x_i ]\}$ is:
\begin{align*} 
U(x^2,P_n) &=  \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\frac{b^2}{n^2} \frac{b}{n} \\
&= b^3 \frac{1}{n^3} \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
&= b^3 \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6n^3}.
\end{align*}

The lower Riemann sum

$$ L(f,P_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i - x_{i-1})$$
where $m_i = \inf\{f(x): x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]\}.$ 
is

\begin{align*} 
L(x^2,P_n) &=  \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)^2\frac{b^2}{n^2} \frac{b}{n} \\
&= \frac{b^3}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2 + 1 -2k) \\
&= \frac{b^3}{n^3} \Big(  \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \big(\sum_{k=1}^n  1\big) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n k \Big) \\ 
&=\frac{b^3}{n^3} \Big( \frac{n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + n - 2 \frac{n (n+1)}{2} \Big)\\
&= \frac{b^3}{n^3}\Big( \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} + n -n(n+1)\Big)
\end{align*}

We have the following inequalities

$$ L(x^2,P_n) \leq \mathcal L(f = x^2) \leq \mathcal U(f = x^2) \leq U(x^2,P_n) $$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ on both sides we have 
$$ \frac{b^3}{3}\leq \mathcal L(f = x^2) \leq \mathcal U(f = x^2) \leq \frac{b^3}{3}$$
All the inequalities are therefore equalities and $x^2$ is integrable on $[0,b]$ with
$$ \int_0^b x^2 dx = \frac{b^3}{3}.$$

For $0< a < b$,

$$ \int_a^b x^2 = \int_0^b x^2 dx - \int_0^a x^2 dx = \frac{b^3-a^3}{3}.$$

Since the function  $x \mapsto x^2$ is symmetric we can also deduce the result $\forall a< b \in \mathbb{R}$.